# How do I go about adding a library to gradle that is on Maven Central?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

https://github.com/premnirmal/Magnet

That is the library I'm trying to add to my project. WHere am I supposed to add

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.premnirmal.magnet</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this is `maven dependency` and you shoud add this on your `pom.xml` file

Comment: @hrskrs Yeah, I read that elsewhere, but I don't have a pom.xml in my project structure.

Comment: what are you using? Eclipse, Android Studio?

Comment: @hrskrs I'm using android studio

Comment: @stack lets try my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use maven central, add this in your `build.gradle` in your module. It will be probably `app`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.premnirmal.magnet:library:1.1.1'
}
```

Additionally you have to have added `jcentral()` in your project `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    ...
}

...

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**ADVICE**

If you have conf from `prom.xml` from **maven** and you want o to change it to **gradle** configuration it works as is shown in example below:

In maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>grup.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>artefact_id</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION_1</version>
</dependency>
```

In gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'grup.artefact_id:VERSION_1'
}
```